# Laravel socialite popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I'm following this instruction from another thread. [Simple example of popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716669/simple-example-of-popup-authentication-with-facebook-graph-api). The problem is I cant make it work on my Laravel app. I'm not quite knowledgeable about cookie and I'm not sure what to do with `$('#UserInfo').text($.cookie("some_cookie"));` in the code.

> I have made the facebook login to popup. The problem is that when I
>   was successfully logged-in, It wont close the popup instead, it loads
>   the redirect path to it.
>
> I want to close the popup window once successfully logged in and then
>   load the next route to the parent.

```
<input id="btn-facebook" type="button" value="Connect with Facebook" />
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.cookie.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    var signinWin;
    $('#btn-facebook').click(function () {
         //   var pos = screenCenterPos(800, 500);
            signinWin = window.open("{!!URL::to('facebook')!!}", "SignIn", "width=780,height=410,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,resizable=0,location=0,menuBar=0,left=" + 500 + ",top=" + 200);
            setTimeout(CheckLoginStatus, 2000);
            signinWin.focus();
            return false;
        });

    function CheckLoginStatus() {
        if (signinWin.closed) {
            $('#UserInfo').text($.cookie("some_cookie"));
        }
        else setTimeout(CheckLoginStatus, 1000);
    }

</script>
```

Comment: store the protected url in the session > connect with oAuth in popup, Authenticate successfully> cookie will be updated for your site as authenticated just close the popup, redirect to the protected url from the session storage.

Comment: By close the popup I mean You can always control the child popups from the parent, write a small js code to do that

Comment: Which Laravel version are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once you get successfully authenticated with the facebook API. Facebook will redirect you to the path that you set for redirection (default behaviour).

This path is same that you set in facebook API Dashboard for your application. Once you get redirected to the configured path from facebook, you have to manage your sessions, cookies etc from this point forward on.

Let us know if this helped you or not.

Answer (score 3):

Laravel support social integration and has official packages. [Socialite for Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/socialite)

It has great documentation and excellent code sample.

For your problem. I'll try to explain what your code does:

First. You have a code that opens a new window

```
signinWin = window.open("{!!URL::to('facebook')!!}", "SignIn", "width=780,height=410,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,resizable=0,location=0,menuBar=0,left=" + 500 + ",top=" + 200);
```

And a code that checks if the window is closed

```
if (signinWin.closed) {
```

This code `$('#UserInfo').text($.cookie("some_cookie"));` only set text value to an element with ID of "UserInfo". It does not do a thing.

In order for the window to close you should add :

```
signinWin.close()
```

to your code. Or you code simply open the window in the same window by setting:

```
window.open("{!!URL::to('facebook')!!}", "_self", "width=780,height=410,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0,resizable=0,location=0,menuBar=0,left=" + 500 + ",top=" + 200);
```